# Importing data from microsoft word to redmine wiki

Tags: wiki, redmine

Is there any software available which can convert .doc/.docx/.odf file to redmine wiki format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [MediaWiki integration patch for Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/attachments/572/redmine-mediawiki.patch)  and its [reference page](http://www.redmine.org/issues/617) .

The reference page says this about the patch:

```
Here's a patch for 0.7 that will add a MediaWiki tab to your project settings and integrate it into the issues pages. You will also need to add:

is_mediawiki tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0', mediawikiurl varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', mediawikinamespace varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''

To the projects table for this to work.
```

If you wanted to import here is a rake file for [importing MediaWiki pages into Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1224)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406533/using-redmine-with-an-external-wiki)